# Turning off co2 tank necessary when regulator psi set to 0?

Tags: carbonation

I am in the habit of turning off my co2 tank even when I have closed the check valve on my regulator and set the psi for the regulator to 0. Is this necessary for safety reasons?

Going even further could I just close the check valve on the regulator and leave the regulator psi at 10 psi (for example)?

The regulator and co2 tank could remain turned off for days if not weeks.

This is the regulator I have
[image: This is the regulator I have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary for safety reasons.  I do it just in case there's a leak in my system, so I don't accidentally drain the CO2

Comment: Denny, just for clarify: you're saying just to close the main valve in the co2 tank? Set the regulator to 0 psi isn't needed, rigth?

Comment: That's correct.  Once the main valve is closed, everything downstream is off.